# Are params values only available in the action you call it in? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am doing a POST request to my create action in my controller with a json like this:

```
{
  "token":"amsdaashdaksjdh" #assume this is a valid token for a user
  "post": {
     "content":"some random text"
     "title":"random title"
   }
}
```

However, I have a before_filter check to see if a User is in my database based on the token like this:

```
before_filter :authenticate


def authenticate
  @user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:token])
  if (@user == nil)
    render :json => {error: "invalid token"}
  end
end
```

It is always giving me the invalid token error...

Comment: If it gives you a token error even if you hardcode the token then maybe something is wrong with how you're authenticating--obviously if it breaks when you're not using `params` it doesn't have anything to do with the params.

Comment: I dont think so because if I put this code directly into my create action it works fine.

Comment: You still need to return false if there's no user (or nil, and true if not), but if you're getting a nil user with a harcoded token, something's wrong. Right now you're returning `nil` if the user is found, or the return value of `render` if the user is nil.

Comment: for some reason params[:token] is returning: ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Rails `before_filter` halts the processing chain when the filter returns `nil` or `false`. Because your `if` statement is the last operation executed, the filter will return `nil`, when `@user` is not `nil` - and this will halt processing.

You could add an `else` block returning true when the user has been found.

```
def authenticate
  @user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:token])
  if @user.nil?
    render :json => {error: "invalid token"}
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: When rendering dosen't it stop the execution?

Comment: At least in newer rails versions. Older versions just throw a `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: still not the issue... for some reason params[:token] is returning: ""